# DownGrade versão do java - The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java

Tenho um projeto em Java 12 que está funcionando 100%.

Meu objetivo é fazer um *downgrade* do Java 12 para o 11, porém quando eu faço essa mudança recebo um erro em umas dependências específicas.

Este é o erro que recebo:

> The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module

Imagem dos erros abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tentei importar as 3 dependências que não estão mais embutidas, se não me engano a partir do Java 9. Porém ainda assim o problema persiste, sendo que no Java 12 funciona normalmente

Comment: Dica: ficaria muito melhor se você escrevesse a mensagem de erro ao invés de postar como imagem.

Comment: Edição feita, obrigado pela dica.!